# scrape table data without attribute using jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I want match list from the site http://www.livescore.com/. The site has 3 tables but these tables have no attribute like `class` or `id`. I used these codes:

```
String URL = "http://www.livescore.com";
Document doc = doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10").get();

String output = "NO";
Elements row = doc.select("table[width=\"468\"] [bgcolor=\"#666666\"] [cellpadding=\"0\"] [border=\"0\"]").select("tr");

for (Element tr : row) {
    Elements clm = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
    output=clm.text();                           
}

t.setText(output);
```

But the table content doesn't appear. How can I do this to bring and also show that table content??? have anyone any idea ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the table content u can catch them into a list and show by the listview .@Imon

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`Elements tables = doc.select("table.league-table");`

That'll select tables with `class=league-table`, which is each score table. Then you can iterate the TRs and TDs as you need.

Comment: but my table has no cls or id .

Comment: I verified from the URL you posted, it has <table class="league-table">. Are you hitting a different URL?

Comment: But i couldn't find the class here.There is no class here.